# How to determine the downloading file type before it actually starts downloading using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am developing a chrome extension, in which I need to determine the original type of the file, and stop the downloading if I encounter certain type of file.
To determine the file type I have the following code.How to put this code to select the downloading file before it actually downloads.

```
 const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('GET', 'unicorn.png');
 xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

 xhr.onload = () => {
 fileType(new Uint8Array(this.response));
 //=> {ext: 'png', mime: 'image/png'}
 };

 xhr.send();
```

File type should be determined using "magic numbers" not string matching.

Comment: Can you do a HEAD request using XMLHttpRequest and get the filename?  I'd wager not, but i'd check.

Answer (score 0):

Set `.responseType` to `"blob"`, check `.type` of `Blob`

```
  xhr.responseType = "blob";

  xhr.onload = () => {
     console.log(xhr.response.type)
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this node module file-type . This should serve your purpose
https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type

Comment: what does node have to do with a chrome extension?

Comment: Sorry did not see the chrome extension part